# Compare negative numbers in bash

Tags: bash, comparison, negative-number

How can i accomplish number comparison involving negative numbers?

```
if [[ "-2" > "-1" ]]; then
    echo "-2 >-1"
else
    echo "-2 <=-1"
fi
```

I also tried

```
if [ '-2' -lt '-1' ]; then
```

but the condition always behaves as if -2 would be greater than -1.

The comparisons work when i do not use negative numbers.

I would like a solution in pure bash if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems to work correctly:

```
if [[ "-2" -gt "-1" ]]; then
    echo "-2 >-1"
else
    echo "-2 <=-1"
fi
```

Output:

```
-2 <=-1
```

You might want to use `((...))` which enables the expression to be evaluated according to rules of Shell Arithmetic.

```
$ ((-2 <= -1)) && echo Smaller or equal || echo Larger
Smaller or equal
$ ((-2 <= -3)) && echo Smaller or equal || echo Larger
Larger
```

Answer (score 6):

`-lt` means *less than*. And indeed, -2 is less than -1.

Your want to use `-gt`, *greater than*.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ a=-2
$ [ $a -le -1 ] && echo "i am lower or equal than -1"
i am lower or equal than -1
```

or

```
if [ $a -le -1 ]; then
  echo "i am lower or equal than -1"
fi
```

To make it "greater than", you need `ge` (greater or equal) or `gt` (strictly greater than).

Comment: `-le` doesn't mean it's lower.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath just updating it, thanks.