# Formatting an if statement in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement

OK i am sure this is an easy question but I am having trouble finding the answer. All I am trying to do is have an if statement that says if $stla is greater than -25 or $stla less than -16. I am pretty sure it is just a syntax thing but I am new to bash and havn't had much luck Googling the answer.

I attached my whole script, the variable assignment seems to be working, so you should need to worry about that. If I disable the if statement and just have echo $stlo it will print every $stlo, so I think the variables are correct.

Right now I just have if ["$stla" -lt "-25"] which returns "line 10: [33.63: command not found" So it is treating $stla as a command and not a number. How do I correct that? And once that is corrected how can I make a or condition to include greater than -25?

Sorry for the simple question, let me know if I need to clarify anything.

```
#!/bin/bash


for file in *.SAC; do

   stla="$(saclst stla f $file)"
   stla=(`echo $stla | awk '{print $2}'`)
   stlo="$(saclst stlo f $file)"
   stlo=(`echo $stlo | awk '{print $2}'`)

   if ["$stla" -gt "-25"]
   then
       echo $stlo
   fi
done
```

Comment: just add a space after `[` and before `]`

Comment: I tried that and all that changed is a space before the number, but the same error. line 10: [: 27.8819: integer expression expected

Comment: Yes, it expects integer expression. Does it say something ambiguous?

Comment: It's worth to spend some time on reading `man bash` and `man test`

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945187/compare-negative-numbers-in-bash  `[ "$stla" -gt "-25" ]`

Comment: Ok, sorry I didn't even read the message...So is the problem that the number is not an integer? if so how do I deal with that? I'll take a look at what you suggested reading so maybe that will help.

Comment: BTW, the `stla=(...)` and `stlo=(...)` parts aren't what you really want. The parentheses there are telling bash to set those variable to arrays (containing a single value) rather than plain variables. Simply removing the parentheses will fix this, but it'd be easier to just add `| awk '{print $2}'` to the original line that sets each one (i.e. `stla="$(saclst stla f $file | awk '{print $2}' )"`). Also, the logic you describe doesn't make sense, because *every* number is greater than -25 or less than -16 (or both, if it's between them).

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Thanks for the info! Yeah, my logic did not make sense, I wasn't thinking that far ahead really. I fixed it and its doing what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
stla=-24
if [[ "$stla" -gt "-25" ]]
then
echo $stla
fi
```

Please note spaces in `if statement`, and fixed a typo in `echo $stla`

If You want to you float:

```
stla=-24.5
if [[ $(echo "$stla > -25"| bc) -eq 1 ]]
then
echo $stla
fi
```

Comment: Ok, that does seem to work if stla=-24. However the actually numbers are floating point. How can I deal with that?

Comment: @gisuser_14213: If you need to deal with floating point numbers, you need to use something other than Bash — Bash arithmetic is integer arithmetic.  Options include: `ksh`, `zsh`, `awk`, Perl, Python, … Any of these could be used, and there are doubtless other options too.

Comment: Look at my edit

Comment: Thanks! I will indeed stop using bash for things like this, but I was able to get it to work for this occasion. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `awk` is probably your best bet, but you can do this in `bash`. See my answer for a general purpose technique for handling these sorts of numerical comparisons in `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `printf` and `tr` to enable fixed-point comparisons:

```
if [ $(printf "%0.2f" "$stla"|tr -d .) -gt -2500 ]
then
    echo "$stlo"
fi
```

This works by first converting `$stla` into an integer. Effectively, it multiplies `$stla` by 100 by printing it with two decimal places and then stripping the decimal point. You manually multiply the other operand to make the comparison maintain its original meaning.